# Jinja2 how to perform advanced slicing

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I've got a list, "foos" and if I've got more than 5 "foos" I want to do something specific to the first 2, and then something specific for the rest.

So I kinda want something like this in HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <p>Foo1<p>
    <p>Foo2<p>
    <div id="collapseMe" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <p>Foo3<p>
        <p>Foo4<p>
        etc...
    </div>
</div>

<a data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMe"><p>Expand</p></a>
```

So, I've kinda solved this in Jinga2 but the solution is very ugly. I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

```
<div id="accordion">
    {% for f in foos  %}
        {% if loop.index <= 2 %}
            <p>{{ f.txt }}</p>
        {% else %}
            {% if loop.index == 3 %}
                <div id="collapseMe" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <p>{{ f.txt }}</p>
            {% else %}
                    <p>{{ f.txt }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if foos | length > 2 %}
    </div>
    <a data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMe"><p>Expand</p></a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Although this works I'm thinking there must be a better way to do it. Unfortunately slice functions are pretty limited in Jinga2 as far as I can see, maybe there's another way around this that I haven't picked up yet? I'm not fully clear on how the Batch function works either, but that may work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build, or find, a filter to pre-slice your `foos` list ahead of the for loop.

```
{% for f in foos|slice:"0:10:2" %}
```

You could move most of your template looping logic into the filter itself or go the easy route and use existing slice notation on a list:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, Undefined

def slice(iterable, pattern):
    if iterable is None or isinstance(iterable, Undefined):
        return iterable

    # convert to list so we can slice
    items = list(iterable)

    start  = None
    end    = None
    stride = None

    # split pattern into slice components
    if pattern:
        tokens = pattern.split(':')
        if len(tokens) >= 1:
            start  = tokens[0]
        if len(tokens) >= 2:
            end    = tokens[1]
        if len(tokens) >= 3:
            stride = tokens[2];

    return items[start:end:stride]
```

Somewhere else, add the filter to your Jinja2 environment.

```
env = Environment()
env.filters['slice'] = slice
```

Note that this works because `[:::]` and `[None:None:None]` are the same slice notation.

Comment: I like the solution, though is it any better than the one above? I'm supposing your point is that it's better to pull out potentially complicated processes from templates and put it in the code instead?

Comment: @edumike exactly; This makes the main template easier to read and the slicing filter can be reused elsewhere. There's most likely a speed advantage too since you're doing the work in a succinct piece of code rather than a custom template graph.